# Why is Browsershot generating the pdf screenshot of the login page instead of the dashboard page?

Tags: php, angular, laravel, browsershot

my task is to generate a pdf screenshot of a certain page. We're using Laravel for the BE (running on `http://127.0.0.1:8000`) and Angular on the FE (running on `http://localhost:4200`).

While trying to run the code below

```
public function generatePdf(Request $request, $id)
{
    $path = public_path("/uploads/");
    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        File::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true);
    }

    Browsershot::url('http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard')
    ->authenticate('test@test.com', 'Monday@123')
    ->select('.ng-star-inserted')
    ->setDelay(3000)
    ->save($path . 'example.pdf');
    echo 'Pdf generated at <i>public/uploads/example.pdf</i>';
}
```

Browsershot generates the pdf screenshot of `http://localhost:4200/#/login` instead of `http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard`. I'm pretty sure I used the correct login credentials in authenticate().

[image]

Comment: If you needed to create a PDF based off of a current page that is protected by an Authentication guard. Since BrowserShot is is essentially accessing this in a new browser session, it does not respect the authenticated state of your apps session. See: https://primitive.dev/blog/bowsershot-pdfs-with-inertia-vue

Comment: Can you suggest other library that can convert URL with Authentication guard to PDF?